# Clone complex array in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have an array like this ...

```
a["a"]                = "aa"
a["b"]                = "ab"
a["c"]                = "ac"
a["d"]["a"]           = "ada"
a["d"]["b"]["a"]      = "adba"
a["e"]["a"]["a"]["a"] = "aeaaa"
```

... and want to clone it

```
clone(b, a)
```

This is what I tried so far :

```
function clone(lhs, rhs){

    for (i in rhs) {
        if (typeof(arr[i]) == "array"){
            clone(lhs[i], rhs[i])
        } else {
            lhs[i] = rhs[i]
        }
    }
}
```

But this clearly doesn't work because `b["d"]` is not created before that `a["d"]["a"]` is asigned to `b["d"]["a"]`. The second problem is that `b["d"]` should be typed as `array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise the subarray before cloning into it:

```
function clone(lhs, rhs) {
    for (i in rhs) {
        if (isarray(rhs[i])) {
            lhs[i][1] = ""
            delete lhs[i][1]
            clone(lhs[i], rhs[i])
        } else {
            lhs[i] = rhs[i]
        }
    }
}
```

The write-value-then-delete it trick is mentioned in the `gawk` man page.

(I also fixed the array detection, using `isarray`.)

Comment: See also `copy_array()` at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62179750/1745001 which I based on `walk_array()` from the gawk manual but is functionally almost identical to the above `clone()` function (with the arguments reversed) except that `copy_array()` will delete the target array (`lhs` above) before populating it and so ensures that the target ends up a copy of the original rather than a superset of the original array plus whatever the target array held previously.